# After upgrading to Windows 8.1, external USB drive disconnecting and reconnecting intermittently

Tags: windows-8, usb-storage

I upgraded from Windows 8.0 to 8.1 recently and ever since the external USB drive (with power supply) connected via a powered USB hub started disconnecting and then automatically connecting after a few seconds. Here is what I did:

1. Checked event log - nothing is there!
2. Removed the drive from the USB hub and directly connected to the laptop USB port (error still coming)
3. I checked the power option and kept the hard drive to be always on, but did not solve the problem

Any ideas what could be the issue? I have seen a Microsoft KB article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2416007/en-us that discusses the same issue, but it is only for Windows 7.

The pattern is, it happens about 15 minutes after I switch on the laptop and then after that every 15 to 20 minutes.

Comment: There's plenty of posts on SuperUser about re-connecting USB devices. Google "usb reconnecting site:superuser.com" or saerch "usb reconnecting" on SU.

Comment: Thanks, tried quite a few articles that matched my configuration, still not solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps that Microsoft explained in the USB Blog:

**Help! After installing Windows 8.1, my USB drive disappears or file transfers stop unexpectedly**
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/usbcoreblog/archive/2013/11/01/help-after-installing-windows-8-1-my-usb-drive-disappears-or-file-transfers-stop-unexpectedly-r-a-post-title.aspx

Comment: This is a good article. However, it looks like it gives solution for mass usb devices (i guess usb dongle etc.) did not find the UID and PID number as mentioned in the article.

Comment: comment to the blog and post your USB device name so that MS can test it and fix it.

Comment: This seems to have fixed my problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISR0wGXJb_Q, I got the link at the bottom of your article but it is little different from the article itself. It looked at a different property.